# HTML How to get consistent result on IE and chrome when using min in html tag input

Tags: html, css

I am using min option in html tag input but it is showing different visual display on IE (version 11) and chrome (version 46.0.2490.71)
The exact problem is that input fields are getting extra long when I open this page using chrome. While in IE it is getting displayed as I want it (and same as when I don't use min)

Note: To see the difference, please open the html file in IE as from jsfiddle the display will always be what I don't want (with extra long input fields)

The sample jsfiddle is: [min demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddle300/4Leer6a9/4/)

Can you please suggest me a way to have same display on IE and chrome while using min in html tag input type="number"

HTML Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CommDesk AdminPage</title>
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                addPlusSign();
                $(".btn1").click(function(){
                    $(".expand1").toggle();
                    var btn1Text = $(".btn1").text();
                    if(btn1Text.indexOf("+") > -1){
                        var temp = btn1Text.replace(/\+|\-/ig, '-');
                        $(".btn1").text(temp);
                    } else if (btn1Text.indexOf("-") > -1){
                        var temp = btn1Text.replace(/\+|\-/ig, '+');
                        $(".btn1").text(temp);
                    }
                });
            })
            function addPlusSign(){
                if($(".expand1")){
                    var btn1Text = $(".btn1").text();
                    $(".btn1").text(btn1Text + " [+]");
                }
            }
            $(function () {
                $('.admin-form')
                //we need to save values from all inputs with class 'admin-input'
                .find(':input.admin-input')
                .each(function () {
                    //save old value in each input's data cache
                    $(this).data('oldValue', $(this).val())
                })
                .end()
                .submit(function (ev) {
                    var changed = false;
                    $(':input.admin-input', this).filter(function () {
                        if($(this).val() != $(this).data('oldValue')){
                            changed = true;
                        }
                    });
                    if($(this).hasClass('changed') && (!changed)){
                        alert("None of the thresholds were changed!");
                        ev.preventDefault()
                    }
                    if($(this).hasClass('changed') && changed){
                        var allowSubmit = window.confirm("You have set a unique threshold for one or more sub-elements below. Are you sure you want to reset them all?")
                        if (!allowSubmit)
                        ev.preventDefault()
                    }
                });
            });
            $(document).on('input', '.admin-input', function(){
                $(this).closest('form').addClass('changed');
            });
        </script>

        <style>
        .expand1 { display: none;
        }
        .btn1 { cursor: pointer;
        }
        body {
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
        font: 15px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        table#t02, #t02 th, #t02 td {
            border: none;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            font-size:90%;
            font-weight:normal;
        }

        #button1{
            position: relative;
            top:10px;
            left:75%;
            color: white;
            background-color: rgb(0,89,132);
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" method="post" class="admin-form">
            <div style="float:left; width:50%">
                <table id="t02" class="table2">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th style="padding:0 10px 0 0;">Green</th>
                        <th colspan="3" style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Yellow</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Red</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="btn1" style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"><b>Call Volume</b></td>
                        <td>&lt</td>
                        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="number", class="admin-input", name="acd_call_volume_good_high", min="0", value="50"></td>
                        <td><input type="number", class="admin-input", name="acd_call_volume_warning_low", min="50", value="50"></td>
                        <td>to</td>
                        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="number", class="admin-input", name="acd_call_volume_warning_high", min="50", value="100"></td>
                        <td>&gt</td>
                        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="number", class="admin-input", name="acd_call_volume_critical_low", min="100", value="100"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="expand1">Day of Job (DOJ)</td>
                        <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
                        <td class="expand1"><input type="number", name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Day of Job (DOJ)", min="0", value="50"></td>
                        <td class="expand1"><input type="number", name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Day of Job (DOJ)", min="50", value="50"></td>
                        <td class="expand1">to</td>
                        <td class="expand1"><input type="number", name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Day of Job (DOJ)", min="50", value="100"></td>
                        <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
                        <td class="expand1"><input type="number", name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Day of Job (DOJ)", min="100", value="100"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" id="button1" style="height:50px; width:100px"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.expand1 { display: none;
}
.btn1 { cursor: pointer;
}
body {
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
font: 15px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table#t02, #t02 th, #t02 td {
border: none;
border-collapse: collapse;
font-size:90%;
font-weight:normal;
}

#button1{
position: relative;
top:10px;
left:75%;
color: white;
background-color: rgb(0,89,132);
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Why not address this in CSS and ditch the ancient style table layout?  Also, some indentation/formatting of your code would go a long way in making it more readable for those trying to answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for reply Mike. I have tried to do the indenting (my bad for missing it earlier). About doing the change in CSS, actually this is the smallest subset of a webpage. The html, css and jscript code for this webpage is being generated by perl code dynamically depending on various factors. So I am trying to minimize the amount of code changes so tried to search and use shortest possible option. But if you can suggest me something using css then I can definitely work on that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using min option in html tag input but it is showing different
>   visual display

The `min` attribute for number inputs sets the smallest value a user can enter. It has nothing to do with the size of the input.

If you want to limit how wide these input fields can get, you need to use `max-width` in your CSS file:

```
input[type=number] {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

However, this doesn't prevent the fields from being smaller than 100px. If you want it to always be a specific width, just use `width` instead.

You also don't need those commas separating the attributes.

Mike is correct in that you should do the layout with CSS instead of a table if possible, but this will address the issue in your question. I would suggest reading about [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you decide to get rid of the table.

Runnable snippet below:

```css
// ADD THIS CSS
input[type=number] {
  max-width: 100px;
}

.expand1 { display: none;
}
.btn1 { cursor: pointer;
}
body {
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
font: 15px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table#t02, #t02 th, #t02 td {
border: none;
border-collapse: collapse;
font-size:90%;
font-weight:normal;
}

#button1{
position: relative;
top:10px;
left:75%;
color: white;
background-color: rgb(0,89,132);
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" method="post" class="admin-form">
<div style="float:left; width:50%">
<table id="t02" class="table2">
<tr>
<th style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"></th>
<th></th>
<th style="padding:0 10px 0 0;">Green</th>
<th colspan="3" style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Yellow</th>
<th></th>
<th style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Red</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="btn1" style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"><b>Call Volume</b></td>
<td>&lt</td>
<td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="number" class="admin-input" name="acd_call_volume_good_high" min="0" value="50"></td>
<td><input type="number", class="admin-input" name="acd_call_volume_warning_low" min="50" value="50"></td>
<td>to</td>
<td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="number" class="admin-input" name="acd_call_volume_warning_high" min="50" value="100"></td>
<td>&gt</td>
<td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="number" class="admin-input" name="acd_call_volume_critical_low" min="100" value="100"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" class="expand1">Day of Job (DOJ)</td>
<td class="expand1">&lt</td>
<td class="expand1"><input type="number" name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Day of Job (DOJ)" min="0" value="50"></td>
<td class="expand1"><input type="number" name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Day of Job (DOJ)" min="50" value="50"></td>
<td class="expand1">to</td>
<td class="expand1"><input type="number" name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Day of Job (DOJ)" min="50" value="100"></td>
<td class="expand1">&gt</td>
<td class="expand1"><input type="number" name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Day of Job (DOJ)" min="100" value="100"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" id="button1" style="height:50px; width:100px"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Sources:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-min-and-max-attributes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width

Comment: Thank you BSMP. The CSS option you suggested has fixed the problem for me. And special thanks for directing me to flexbox. I think I can definitely use it to make things better.